# Failed to start Orchard.exe form command line and getting error

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I was trying to run Orchard.exe form Orchard.Web folder location by typing the command \bin\orchard.exe and getting the **Failed to initialize Orchard session.** error and also there was a UnauthorizedAccessException. My goal was to create an orchard theme form the command prompt. But getting the error. The error details are the following:

**Note:** tried to run Orchard.exe form different ways like opening the command prompt form run prompt, from admin mode etc. But every time getting the same error. And also changed the file permission to Full Access for all users and Network Service and IIS users

```
C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard.Web>bin\orchard.exe
Initializing Orchard session. (This might take a few seconds...)
log4net:ERROR OrchardFileAppender: Failed to open [C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Or
chard.Web\App_Data\Logs\orchard-error]. Attempting [C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\O
rchard.Web\App_Data\Logs\orchard-error-1] instead.
log4net:ERROR OrchardFileAppender: Failed to open [C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Or
chard.Web\App_Data\Logs\orchard-debug]. Attempting [C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\O
rchard.Web\App_Data\Logs\orchard-debug-1] instead.
log4net:ERROR OrchardFileAppender: Failed to open [C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Or
chard.Web\App_Data\Logs\orchard-recipes]. Attempting [C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src
\Orchard.Web\App_Data\Logs\orchard-recipes-1] instead.

Error starting up Orchard command line host
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Access to the path 'C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard.Web\App_Data\Dependencies
\dependencies.xml' is denied.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\De
moOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard.Web\App_Data\Dependencies\dependencies.xml' is den
ied.

Stack Trace:

[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Orc
hard.Web\App_Data\Dependencies\dependencies.xml' is denied.]
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, I
nt32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions o
ptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolea
n useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
   at Orchard.FileSystems.AppData.AppDataFolder.CreateFile(String path) in C:\De
moOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard\FileSystems\AppData\AppDataFolder.cs:line 128
   at Orchard.FileSystems.Dependencies.DefaultDependenciesFolder.WriteDependenci
es(String persistancePath, IEnumerable`1 dependencies) in C:\DemoOrchard\orchard
\src\Orchard\FileSystems\Dependencies\DefaultDependenciesFolder.cs:line 102
   at Orchard.FileSystems.Dependencies.DefaultDependenciesFolder.StoreDescriptor
s(IEnumerable`1 dependencyDescriptors) in C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard\Fil
eSystems\Dependencies\DefaultDependenciesFolder.cs:line 57
   at Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionLoaderCoordinator.SetupExtensions(
) in C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\Extensions\ExtensionLoaderCo
ordinator.cs:line 77
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.SetupExtensions() in C:\DemoOrchard
\orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.cs:line 232
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.BuildCurrent() in C:\DemoOrchard\or
chard\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.cs:line 118
   at Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.Orchard.Environment.IOrchardHost.In
itialize() in C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.
cs:line 82
   at Orchard.Commands.CommandHostAgent.CreateHostContainer() in C:\DemoOrchard\
orchard\src\Orchard\Commands\CommandHostAgent.cs:line 198
   at Orchard.Commands.CommandHostAgent.StartHost(TextReader input, TextWriter o
utput) in C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard\Commands\CommandHostAgent.cs:line 1
19

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Failed to initialize Orchard session.

C:\DemoOrchard\orchard\src\Orchard.Web>
```

Do you know any steps could solve this issue?

Comment: Seems your user doesn't have (write) rights on the App_Data directory

Comment: i checked that the user had the write permission and the read only permission is unchecked. but still same issue. :(

Comment: You have set the permissions for all whole App_Data directory and all Sub-Folders and Files...
After that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

- Rebuild the solution then try it again
- Move the solution to another folder
- Move the solution to another drive
- Try to download the source code again
- Try with other Orchard versions